# Keeps getting gibberish in client side while trying to get value in hebrew

Tags: java

I made a java server which the client requests info and gets response from the server. I am using `BufferedWriter` in order to send info to the client, and the info is in hebrew. The problem is that the client just gets gibberish if the server sends hebrew to him. I already tried different encoding, like ISO-8859-8, UTF-8, Unicode and so on, but none of them helped. I made a check and in the server side, and the string in the server is fine, in hebrew and I also made it so save it to file in hebrew and it worked. I really don't know what to do.. I tried almost every solution here and nothing worked.

Comment: You are probably on the right track with your attention to encoding issues.  In particular, client and server must agree on the encoding, and it must be one that can encode all the characters involved (I would recommend UTF-8).  Beyond that, there's not much we can say without a [mcve].

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to check the Content-Type header in the response, as well as the character encoding actually chosen by the browser. What are they? Or is this not a web application, but a custom client-server protocol? In that case, why do you suspect the server? How are you handling decoding in the client?

Comment: What is the client? Browser? Custom app?

Comment: The client just gets a series of bytes; it depends on which encoding the client uses to decode the bytes to characters.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I tried to make the string from the server to UTF-8 like this: 
`changes = new String(changes.getBytes(), "UTF-8");`
and get the string from client like this: 
`new String(input.getBytes(), "UTF-8")`
but it didn't work.
@erickson I wrote my decoding right here^, this is an android app.
@TamasHegedus android app
@ZhongYu i Tried many different encodings to decode in the client side, but none of them worked.

Comment: The mechanism you describe for UTF-8 encoding is nonsense.  It risks producing gibberish, and the *best* you can hope for is that it has no net effect.  The encoding is not a property of the `String` (a ***character*** sequence) containing the data; it is a property of the stream of ***bytes*** you send from server to client.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well I tried what you said, and it didn't entirely work, but it made me tinker a little bit about my server, and I found out that the `BufferedWriter` made the problem. Instead, I used the `DataOutputStream` and it worked fine. I tried to find some other write methods in  the `BufferedWriter` and all it had is `br.write(someString)`, while the `DataOutputStream` has a method called `.writeUTF(someString)`, and it made the job.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `BufferedWriter` for it, I just tinkered a little bit and found out that if you want to write something with UTF-8 encoding (e.g some non-Latin characters) you could just use the `DataOutputStream` variable, which has the method `writeUTF()`.
It goes like this:

```
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.writeUTF(someString);
    out.flush();
```

Comment: This is correct only if the receiving end expects to receive data in length + data format, with the data expressed in [the *modified UTF-8 variant* used internally by the JVM and Java class files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8).  Approximately, that means only if the client reads it via `DataInputStream.readUTF()`.  It is *not* correct for general-purpose clients such as web browsers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger for me it worked with `BufferedReader`, but anyway in my case it was android app. I know it would be useful for other users.

Comment: Now that you've provided at least a tiny bit of code to work with, I can suggest that for a general-purpose UTF-8 character stream you want to wrap the socket's `OutputStream` in an `OutputStreamWriter` configured to use UTF-8.  `OutputStreamWriter` and `OutputStreamReader` are Java's standard bridges between character streams and byte streams.